# Group by 2 columns regardless of order

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following query

```
select a.message, a.sender_id, a.rec_id, a.id, a.is_seen, b.total_msg, b.last_id, users.name
from tbl_message a left join users on (users.id=a.sender_id)
inner join
  (select sender_id, rec_id, max(id) last_id, count(*) total_msg
         from tbl_message group by sender_id,rec_id
  )b on a.id=b.last_id 
order by a.id desc
```

gives the result as below:

```
+----------------------------+-----------+--------+----+---------+-----------+---------+------+
| message                    | sender_id | rec_id | id | is_seen | total_msq | last_id | name |
+----------------------------+-----------+--------+----+---------+-----------+---------+------+
| latest testing l5 aug      |         2 |     1  | 12 |      0  |       5   |     12  | B    |
| testing                    |         1 |     2  | 11 |      1  |       3   |     11  | A    |
| this msg of A              |         1 |     3  |  9 |      0  |       1   |      9  | A    |
| this is again 3rd msg of C |         3 |     1  |  6 |      1  |       3   |      6  | C    |
+----------------------------+-----------+--------+----+---------+-----------+---------+------+
```

I want the result as:

For `sender_id/rec_id = 1 or 2` `id = 12` and for `sender_id/rec_id = 1 or 3` `id = 9`

Comment: Please clarify what is the expected output.

Comment: Please don't reference images offsite, include them in the question directly.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to group rows by the `sender_id,rec_id` participants pair regardless of which order they appear in (i.e. `sender_id,rec_id` or `rec_id,sender_id` should be part of the same group).

If so, change your `group by` from

```
group by sender_id, rec_id
```

to

```
group by least(sender_id,rec_id), greatest(sender_id,rec_id)
```

Using `greatest` and `least` will ensure that each conversation will be grouped by the participants regardless of which order they appear in.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to join with all the grouped columns

Try this

```
 SELECT a.message
    ,a.sender_id
    ,a.rec_id
    ,a.id
    ,a.is_seen
    ,b.total_msg
    ,b.last_id
    ,users.NAME
FROM tbl_message a
LEFT JOIN users ON (users.id = a.sender_id)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sender_id
        ,rec_id
        ,max(id) last_id
        ,count(*) total_msg
    FROM tbl_message
    GROUP BY sender_id
        ,rec_id
    ) b ON a.sender_id=b.sender_id and a.rec_id=b.rec_id and a.id = b.last_id
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove one column from the GROUP BY clause of the derived table (subquery)

```
select a.message, a.sender_id, a.rec_id, a.id, a.is_seen, b.total_msg, b.last_id, users.name
from tbl_message a left join users on (users.id=a.sender_id)
inner join
  (select sender_id, rec_id, max(id) last_id, count(*) total_msg
         from tbl_message group by sender_id 
  )b on a.id=b.last_id 
order by a.id desc
```

I would expect this to result in rows only for the following

```
SenderID ID
2        12
1        9
3        6
```